# How to manage indentation in python?

Tags: python, string, indentation

I want to generate strings that have built in indentation to them and I want to make them the values of the map, so that when I print through the keys of the map I will have an output like:

```
[
    {
        "student": "Zara",
        "grades": [
             [ 4.02, 2.3,4.5,6.7
               ,6.07, 7.08
             ]
         ]
    } 
]
```

Comment: You want to print a data structure with indenting?

Comment: Yes, when I go through the map and print all the values, I want the indentation to appear as formatted above.